# What is the relationship of SMB and SAMR protocol?

Tags: java, smb, jcifs, msrpc, ms-samr

I try to create user in samba server and found out that [samr protocol](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-samr/96952411-1d17-4fe4-879c-d5b48a264314) is used for that

Based on
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-samr/084da2e7-0ba0-44fc-8f17-e8a200c69eb5

> RPC clients for this protocol MUST use RPC over TCP/IP for the
> SamrValidatePassword method and MUST use RPC over SMB for the
> SamrSetDSRMPassword method.

I understood that there are some relationship between smb and samr.

Could you please explain the hierarchy of of those protocols ?

I want to know it because most articles mention that Samba server support smb protocol and from java I can use jcifs library.

> JCIFS is an Open Source client library that implements the CIFS/SMB
> networking protocol in 100% Java

Also I noticed that this library contains classes where you can notice **samr** in the name https://github.com/codelibs/jcifs/tree/master/src/main/java/jcifs/dcerpc/msrpc

So what is relationship of **samr** and **smb** ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51350779/2674303)

> IP < TCP < SMB Named Pipes < MSRPC

- MSRPC works over SMB Named Pipes
- SAMR works over MSRPC